# Bounded continuous Riesz isomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, vector-lattices

I want to know if $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are Riesz isomorphic is it true that $BC(X)$ (the space of bounded continuous functions on $X$) and $BC(Y)$ also have to be Riesz isomorphic.

I already found the contradiction for the inverse because $BC(N)$ and $BC(aN)$ are Riesz isomorphic while $C(N)$ and $C(aN)$ are definitely not!

I can probably use this hint but this only helps me when $X$ and $Y$ are real-compact.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real-compact topological spaces.
Suppose $T$ is a linear bijection $C(X)\to C(Y)$ that is multiplicative, i.e.,
$T(fg) = T(f) \cdot T(g)\,\,\, (f, g \in C(X))$.
Then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic. More explicitly: There exists a homeomorphism $\tau: Y \to X$
for which
$T(f) ≔ f \circ \tau\,\,\, (f \in C(X))$.

Can anyone help me if there is a counter example or if this theorem is true!

Thanks a lot,,

Comment: What do you mean by Riesz isomorphic?

Comment: A Riesz isomorphism of a Riesz space  onto a Riesz space  is a linear
bijection :  ⟶  with
( ∨ ) =  ∨ , ( ∧ ) =  ∧  (,  ∈ ).

Comment: And we say E and F are Riesz isomorphic if there is a Riesz isomorphism from E to F